# What is accepted practice for indenting multiple implementations of interfaces

Tags: java, interface, standards, indentation

If I have a class that implements many listeners, what is the accepted spacing?

Right now I am doing this:

```
public class MyClass 
    implements interface1,
    interface2,
    interface3,
    interface4,
    interface5 {
```

Comment: The accepted spacing is what your company/project accept as accepted spacing. I personally keep them on the same line when manageable. That being said, the interface names should be capitalized (by convention) in PascalCase, as class names are.

Comment: A class which implements that many interfaces would make me ask: Why does this class that much? A more dedicated class also reduces the amount of implemented interfaces.

Comment: @Tom Activities / fragments in Android, in particular several DialogFragments for CRUD operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just go with:

```
public class MyClass implements Interface1, Interface2, 
        Interface3, Interface4, Interface5 {
```

Here, the second line has two indentations.

Just make sure everybody in your organization uses the same style.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to a Java Coding Convention from Sun Micro-systems way back in 1997.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) While certainly dated, this is the best "official" document describing coding conventions in java I can find. It says to align new lines to the same bracket/space as the above line.

However, what I typically do for personal projects that don't have a company enforced coding convention, is new line, double tab, then go out to about the same length as the first line, then repeat as needed.

In short, unless some one tells you otherwise, just do what ever lets you read it the best.

EDIT: [Here is a link to the Google coding conventions for java.](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.5-line-wrapping) What it says is to basically do whatever fits the situation, and it is up to the programmer writing it to decide what that is.